# REST HTTPS login with Ruby - Connection Reset by peer

Tags: ruby, rest, https

I am trying to do a REST API login over HTTPS.  I keep getting `Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)`:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

uri = URI.parse("https://.../login.jsp")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req['userid'] = 'myemail%40hostname.com'
req['passwd'] = 'mypassword'
res = https.request(req)
puts res.body
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  The corresponding cURL command that works without a hitch is:

```
curl --user-agent "MyUserAgent" --cookie-jar cookiefile -o - --data 'userid=myemail%40hostname.com&passwd=mypassword' https://.../login.jsp
```

(I haven't gotten to dealing with capturing the cookie file yet, I'm just trying to get the login to work)

Suggestions appreciated!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I needed to set form data for this work.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

uri = URI.parse("https://.../login.jsp")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req.set_form_data('userid' => 'myemail@hostname.com', 'passwd' => 'mypassword')
res = https.request(req)
puts res
```